# How do i update value of array in firestore db

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a react app and i'm using firebase/firestore for the database.
I want to have a textarea that updates the name of an object inside of an array in the firestore db.

The structure of the db looks like this:
[image]

I want to update the name property of one of the objects in the "categories" array.

The code I've written so far looks like this:

```js
    const updateCategoryInfo = async (categoryId: number, categoryName: string) => {
      await updateDoc(docRef, {
        [`categories[${categoryId}].name`]: categoryName
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Category updated succesfully!")
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error updating categoryname", error)
      })
    }
```

The code gives this error:

[image]

Comment: What value holds the `categoryId` variable?

Comment: @AlexMamo It holds a number between 0-5 to choose which object in the "categories" array should be updated. There are 5 different textareas and the number gets determined based on which textarea you type in

Comment: You can't target specific array elements for update in Firestore.  You have to read the document, modify the array in memory, then write the updated field back to the document.